# How am I suppose to use OnLongClickListener on specific Marker inside google map

Tags: android, google-maps

First of all I create Arraylist where I put all my markers.

```
 markerArrayList = new ArrayList<Marker>();


    marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(51.1117744, 17.0353596))
            .title("Giselle French Bakery Cafe")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    marker1.setDraggable(false);
    marker1.setTag(0);


    marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(51.110969, 17.031510))
            .title("Second Bakery Cafe")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    marker2.setDraggable(false);
    marker2.setTag(1);

    markerArrayList.add(marker1);
    markerArrayList.add(marker2);
```

Next I have used a LongClickListener on map like here, and try to check which one is clicked:

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            for (Marker marker : markerArrayList) {
                if (Math.abs(marker.getPosition().latitude - latLng.latitude) < 0.005
                        && Math.abs(marker.getPosition().longitude - latLng.longitude) < 0.005) {
                    onMarkerLongClick(marker);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

but the problem is, that no matter where I use long click on map, it always choose the first one in a row from arraylit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check some solution I have found the best answer if the markers are set really close one by one.

Here is the fragment of code which should work properly

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            for (Marker marker : markerArrayList) {
                if (Math.abs(marker.getPosition().latitude - latLng.latitude) < 0.001
                        && Math.abs(marker.getPosition().longitude - latLng.longitude) < 0.001) {
                    onMarkerLongClick(marker);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markers are placed closer than the difference you check in `onMapLongClick(...)`, which leaves you with a very small difference window. Try decreasing from `0.005` to `0.00005` or moving first marker further away from the second one (try checking these coordinates: `LatLng(51.15, 17.00)`).

Comment: It doesnt change anything. It still took the first marker in a row :(